# asp.net mvc 5 An exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm getting an error which I can't find the solution to, it's most likely a problem of my models which i'm trying to connect, the error i get is the following: "An exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code" when i try to iterate through each column. So basically one of the tables has less records than the others? How do i solve this? The iteration is in the View -> item.Contacts.Count()

The program is supposed to take some columns of choosing from tables: Contatti, Contacts and Companies which are at different locations and bring them together (which happen in the list of the GET method in the controller), Contatti is a sql server table imported to the project as .edmx, the other 2 are local to the project seeded tables. the code is the following:

Model that brings the tables together:

```
public partial class ContactsUni2
{

    [Key, ForeignKey("Contatti")]
    public int ContattoID { get; set; }
    public List<Contatti> Contattis { get; set; }
    public List<Companies> Companies { get; set; }
    public List<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    public virtual Contatti Contatti { get; set; }
    public virtual Contact Contact { get; set; }
    public virtual Companies Company { get; set; }
}
```

Contact Model:

```
public class Contact
{
    [Key]
    public int ContactId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Companies")]
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Companies> Companies { get; set; }
    [Required]
    //public virtual Contatti Contatti { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Contatti> Contatti { get; set; }
}
```

Companies model:

```
public class Companies
{
    [Key]
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string CompanyAddress { get; set; }
    public string CompanyCity { get; set; }
    public string CompanyState { get; set; }
    public string CompanyZip { get; set; }
    public string CompanyArea { get; set; }
}
```

Contatti Model:

```
public partial class Contatti
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Contact")]
    public int ContattoID { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Via { get; set; }
    public string Citta { get; set; }
    public string Stato { get; set; }
    public string CodicePostale { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contact { get; set; }
}
```

Controller GET:

```
// GET: ContactsUni21
    public ActionResult Index(String Page)
    {
        ContactsUni2 CU = new ContactsUni2();
        CU.Contattis = db.Contattis.ToList();
        CU.Contacts = db.Contacts.ToList();
        CU.Companies = db.Companies.ToList();
        List<ContactsUni2> contactlist = new List<ContactsUni2>();
        contactlist.Add(CU);
        return View(contactlist);
    }
```

View:

```
<body>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Contatti.ContattoID)
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Contatti.Nome)
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Contatti.Citta)               
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Contatti.CodicePostale)
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Contatti.Email)
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Contact.Address)
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Contact.CompanyId)
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Contact.ContactId)
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Company.CompanyName)

        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model.ToList())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < @item.Contacts.Count(); i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @item.Contattis[i].ContattoID
                    @item.Contattis[i].Nome
                    @item.Contattis[i].Citta                                              
                    @item.Contattis[i].CodicePostale
                    @item.Contattis[i].Email
                    @item.Contacts[i].Address
                    @item.Contacts[i].CompanyId
                    @item.Contacts[i].ContactId


                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ContattoID }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ContattoID }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ContattoID })
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: "How do i solve this?" Which problem? That the collections are different sizes or that you are trying to pull more items than are there?  Why not just loop over both collections separately?

Comment: Probably (int i = 0; i < @item.Contacts.Count(); i++)  i is greater than amount of Contattis (@item.Contattis[i]). In other words Contattis has less elements that Contacts.

Comment: i tried looping separately but i get only the data from Contacts table, not from contattis, is it because it's an sql server table or the data model is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had a chance to check this, but something like this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.ToList())
{
    //for (int i = 0; i < @item.Contacts.Count(); i++)
    foreach (var contact in item)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @contact.ContattoID
                @contact.Nome
                @contact.Citta                                              
                @contact.CodicePostale
                @contact.Email
                @contact.Address
                @contact.CompanyId
                @contact.ContactId


            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ContattoID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ContattoID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ContattoID })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
}
```